# How to set the distance between ticks in plotly?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I am using plotly to create dendrograms with different amounts of leaves. I aim to set the distance between the y-axis ticks to be exactly the same for all the different dendrograms. So far I have tried setting the height of the figure to depend on the number of leaves like this:

```
fig.update_layout(
    width=width,
    height=num_ticks * 50,
    margin={'l': 0, 'r': 0, 't': 0, 'b': 0}
)
```

While this ensures the same height ratio of the dendrograms, it seems like the distance in between the y-axis ticks gets smaller for plots with more leaves and, instead, more whitespace is added at the top of the graph. Ideally, I would like to set the distance in px, but I would also be happy to find a solution with a consistent distance between the different plots. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Did you get a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

This whitespace on the top could be added automatically by plotly to fit in the title or other elements of your dendrogram. I would try

```
fig.update_layout(
    width=width,
    height=num_ticks * 50,
    margin=dict(autoexpand = False, t = 0, b = 0, l = 0, r = 0)
)
```